# Extract the values from the array which is inside the object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

if i solve this i will have my desired result for any expert this will take few minutes to guess and i am stuck in this from last 2 hours searching and googling but couldn't found the one i want. Okay so here is the thing ...

I am sending data through ajax to my php by doing JSON.stringify and receving that that to my php in the form of this

```
{"0":["BE","test","test","1993"],"1":["HSSC","test","test","1995"]}
```

All i want to do is to get the values and insert them to the separate variables.

Comment: use `json_decode`

Comment: used it and got this error
`<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: 4096</p>
<p>Message:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/register_account.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 104</p>`

Comment: share your code in your post, which you are currently using

Comment: perfect solved that error actually i was echoing the json_decode my bad. now i get the result as 

`stdClass Object
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => BE
            [1] => jg
            [2] => jhg
            [3] => 1993
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => HSSC
            [1] => sss
            [2] => dfff
            [3] => 1995
        )

)`

one question in this is how should i get the **BE** value 

`$result->[0]->[0]`

Comment: use `json_decode($string, true)` it will convert this to array which will be easy for you to get the record like `$result[0][0]`

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks @AgamBanga. Write your answer as a answer i will select it as right answer so other people will know the right one as well.

Comment: Thanks @SahilGulati

Comment: @RohitPoonia welcome.. friend.. :)

Comment: @SahilGulati Glad it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert the string to array. You can pass the second parameter to this method to convert this to array instead of object. Then you can retrieve the data like

```
$string = '{"0":["BE","test","test","1993"],"1":["HSSC","test","test","1995"]}';
$array = json_decode($string, true);
print_r($array[0][0]);
```

Here's the example of it https://repl.it/HhI8/1